# `x = [lambda: x for x in range(3)]`, what will `x[0]()` return?

Tags: python, lambda

In this code `x = [x for x in range(3)]` global x is equal to [0, 1, 2].

The x in the list comprehension is a local variable.

Then let's define `x = [lambda: x for x in range(3)]`, what will `x[0]()` return? 0? 2?

No, it will return a list, global x itself.

**I want to know why the inner x refers to global x, but not local x?**

Comment: Do you know what `[(lambda: i) for i in range(10)][0]()` returns, and why?

Comment: This question has been solved in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381793/why-do-these-two-x-refer-to-different-variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of the precedence of operators.  Your expression is:

```
x = [lambda: x for x in range(3)]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
x = [(lambda: x) for x in range(3)]
```

This is a list of three functions, each of which refers to the global x.  The lambda creates a scope, and in Python 2, the next scope examined after the local scope is the global scope, so that is where x is found.

This gives you want you want (I think this is what you want):

```
>>> x = [(lambda x=x: x) for x in range(3)]
>>> x[0]()
0
```

Here we make use of the fact that default values are evaluated once, in the current scope, when functions are defined.  This bakes the value of x into each lambda in the list.