# Why do these two 'x' refer to different variable?

Tags: python

In this code, the x in the lambda refers to the x in the for statement. So `y[0]()` returns 2:

```
x = 0
y = [lambda : x for x in range(3)]
y[0]()
```

But in this code, the x in the lambda refers to global x, so `x[0]()` returns global x itself:

```
x = [lambda : x for x in range(3)]
x[0]()
```

I want to know why the x in the lambda refers to the local x in the first piece of code but global x in the second piece of code.

Comment: because of scope ... see :http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` refers to the global `x` in both pieces of code.  Indeed, there is nothing *but* a global `x` in both pieces of code.  There are no local variables here, only global variables.

In the first example, the global value of `x` is 2, because that was the last value assigned to it by the list comprehension.  List comprehensions leak their variables into the enclosing scope as described by @wim.  Since the enclosing scope here is the global scope, the variable `x` is leaked into global scope, overwriting the value 0 that you set earlier.

In the second example, you create the list comprehension, but then assign its value to the (global) variable x.  This overwrites whatever was already in x, so the value of the global variable x is now the list.

In both cases, when you call one of the functions in the list (any one!), it returns the *current* value of `x`.  You can see this here:

```
>>> y = [lambda : x for x in range(3)]
>>> y[0]()
2
>>> x = 88
>>> y[0]()
88
>>> x = [lambda : x for x in range(3)]
>>> y = x
>>> y[0]()
[<function <lambda> at 0x017789B0>,
 <function <lambda> at 0x01828DB0>,
 <function <lambda> at 0x01828F30>]
>>> x = 88
>>> y[0]()
88
```

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are on python 2.x, where in a list comprehension, the temporary variable 'leaks' into the namespace.  You can read about why in [this blog post from Guido](http://python-history.blogspot.com.au/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html).

> In Python 2, the list comprehension "leaks" the loop control variable
>   into the surrounding scope ... This was an artifact of the original
>   implementation of list comprehensions; it was one of Python's "dirty
>   little secrets" for years.

This has been fixed in python 3.

I'm not sure why you are confusing things with the `lambda`, here you will see the same behaviour in this simpler case:

```
>>> x = 'a'
>>> y = [x for x in 'b','c']
>>> x
'c'
>>> x = [x for x in 'b','c']
>>> x
['b', 'c']
```

Comment: Personally I preferred the 'leaking' implementation, as it was then functionally identical to a for loop, which leaves its control variable in scope once finished too.

Comment: Opinions differ I guess .. I do not prefer it, can think of no valid use case for the 'leak' and I did get stung by it once.  I think it was correct for the behavior to be removed, because I see the list comprehension as one logical unit and the control just a free variable rather than a definition, similar to in predicate calculus.

Comment: Yeah, I certainly understand & appreciate the why.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x='a'
>>>x = [lambda : x for x in range(3)]
```

as soon as the iteration starts the `x` gets assigned to `0`, returned from `range()`(and and reference to 'a' is removed). In the final iteration the value of `x` becomes 2, and as soon as the LC exits the LC gets assigned to `x`, so now `x` points to the LC.

example:

```
>>> [x for x in range(3)]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> x     
2
>>> x=[x for x in range(3)]
>>> x
[0, 1, 2]
```